# Android Tethering Turns off straight away

Tags: tethering

From time to time, the tethering on my Nexus 6P, running Android 7.1.1, turns itself off for no reason. It can then take 5 or 6 attempts for it to turn back on.

Trying to turn it on, results in the tethering turning on and then straight back off again.

I managed to capture an adb logcat while this was happening, which can be found here

http://pastebin.com/eykDitb3

Keep Wifi on during sleep is set to Always

My provider is Three in the UK

I'm wondering if this is an issue with android, or my provider.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with a computer, and is off topic. You correctly tagged your question as android, please click on it and read the description :)

Comment: Do you have given permission to use data(internet) for the System app named 'Android System'?

Answer (score 1):

If your Nexus 6P is rooted:

1. Install [Build Prop Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.apps.build.prop.editor) app from the Play Store and launch it.
2. Change `net.tethering.noprovisioning=true`
3. Install [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) app from the Play Store and launch it.
4. In Terminal Emulator, enter the following code sequentially:

   ```
   su
   settings put global tether_dun_required 0
   exit
   reboot
   ```